# Global regex match in while() on backtick result

Tags: regex, perl

This script searches for lines with words and prints them, while **rereading source file in each iteration**:

```
# cat mm.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while( `cat aa` =~ /(\w+)/g ) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

Input file:

```
# cat aa
aa
bb
cc
```

Result:

```
# ./mm.pl
aa
bb
cc
```

Please explain me why running the script isn't **endless**.

In every *while* iteration offset for regex engine **should be reset** because expression is changed (new *cat* is forked).

I thought perl does some kind of caching for *cat* result, but strace claims that *cat* was spawned 4 times (3 for 3 lines + 1 for false while condition):

```
# strace -f ./mm.pl 2>&1 | grep cat | grep -v ENOENT
[pid 22604] execve("/bin/cat", ["cat", "aa"], [/* 24 vars */] <unfinished ...>
[pid 22605] execve("/bin/cat", ["cat", "aa"], [/* 24 vars */] <unfinished ...>
[pid 22606] execve("/bin/cat", ["cat", "aa"], [/* 24 vars */] <unfinished ...>
[pid 22607] execve("/bin/cat", ["cat", "aa"], [/* 24 vars */] <unfinished ...>
```

On the other hand, following example **runs forever**:

```
# cat kk.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $d = 'aaa';
while( $d =~ /(\w+)/g ) {
    print "$1\n";
    $d = 'aaa';
}
```

Where is a difference between the two scripts? What am I missing?

Comment: This is a nice question

Comment: For those, without strace, you can use for example this bash script `mycat` as `for i in aa bb cc; do echo "${i}_$BASHPID"; done` (ofc `chmod 755 mycat`). it will show different `$BASH_PID` for every loop. :)

Comment: Maybe the backtick is reusing the same memory buffer and that fools the /g into thinking it is the same string.

Comment: The `qx` strikes back. The episode V - why do not use backticks... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The position at which `//g` left off is stored in magic added to the scalar against which the matching was performed.

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'$_ = "abc"; Dump($_); /./g; Dump($_);'
SV = PV(0x32169a0) at 0x3253ee0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pPOK)
  PV = 0x323bae0 "abc"\0
  CUR = 3
  LEN = 10
  COW_REFCNT = 1
SV = PVMG(0x326c040) at 0x3253ee0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (SMG,POK,IsCOW,pPOK)
  IV = 0
  NV = 0
  PV = 0x323bae0 "abc"\0
  CUR = 3
  LEN = 10
  COW_REFCNT = 2
  MAGIC = 0x323d050
    MG_VIRTUAL = &PL_vtbl_mglob
    MG_TYPE = PERL_MAGIC_regex_global(g)
    MG_FLAGS = 0x40
      BYTES
    MG_LEN = 1
```

This means the only way the behaviour observed is possible in the backticks example is if the match operator matched against the same scalar all four times it was evaluated! How is that possible? It's because backticks is one of the operators that uses a TARG.

Creating a scalar is relatively expensive since it requires up to three memory allocations! In order to increase performance, a scalar called TARG is associated with each instance of some operators. When an operator with a TARG is evaluated, it may populate the TARG with the value to return and return the TARG (rather than allocating and returning a new one).

"So what?", you might ask. After all, you've already demonstrated that assigning to a scalar resets the match position associated with that scalar. That's what's suppose to happen, but it doesn't for backticks.

Magic not only allows information to be attached to a variable, it also attaches functions to be called under certain conditions. The magic added by `//g` attaches a function that should be called after the scalar is modified (which is indicated by the `SMG` flag in the dump above). This function is what clears the position when a value is assigned to the scalar.

The assignment operator handles the magic properly, but not by the backticks operator. It doesn't expect magic to have been added to its TARG, so it doesn't check if there's any, so the function that clears the match position goes uncalled.

Comment: Sounds like bug to be reported for me.

Comment: @Oleg V. Volkov, It's a bug, but I can't figure out any benefit in fixing it. I can't figure out a situation in which it causes harm, and it actually helped in the OP's case

Comment: @ikegami While it helped, it is also confusing. An endless loop seems to be the naiv expectation.

Comment: @Micha Wiedenmann, Don't get me wrong, people shouldn't rely on the buggy behaviour. I'm just saying that if they accidentally do, their program still works, and that's not a bad thing.